# Tips for improving MariaDB performance and tuning queries

Tags: performance, mariadb, mysqltuner, mariadb-10.6

I'm currently working on optimizing the performance of my MariaDB database and have come across a tool called mysqltuner. I've installed and run mysqltuner on my server, and it provided me with some recommendations and insights into the current state of my MariaDB configuration.

However, I'm looking for advice and additional guidance on how to interpret and implement the suggestions provided by mysqltuner effectively.

I'm using the server for this database only
but user tell me that slow queries because server not properly tuning
MariaDB 10.6, Apache 2.4.52.

How can I interpret the recommendations given by mysqltuner accurately? What do the various metrics and values signify, and how do they relate to the performance of my MariaDB database?

server requirements

```
CPU(s) 32 x Intel(R) Xeon(R) Silver 4314 CPU @ 2.40GHz
RAM 32 GB
```

MYSQL Tuner Output

```
 >>  MySQLTuner 2.2.6
[--] Skipped version check for MySQLTuner script
[OK] Logged in using credentials from Debian maintenance account.
[OK] Operating on 64-bit architecture

-------- Storage Engine Statistics ---------------------------------------------                                                                                        --------------------
[--] Status: +Aria +CSV +InnoDB +MEMORY +MRG_MyISAM +MyISAM +PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA                                                                                         +SEQUENCE
[--] Data in Aria tables: 32.0K (Tables: 1)
[--] Data in MyISAM tables: 13.3M (Tables: 165)
[--] Data in InnoDB tables: 33.4G (Tables: 2578)
[--] Data in MEMORY tables: 0B (Tables: 6)
[OK] Total fragmented tables: 0

[OK] Currently running supported MySQL version 10.6.14-MariaDB-1:10.6.14+maria~u                                                                                        bu2204
-------- Log file Recommendations ----------------------------------------------                                                                                        --------------------
[!!] Log file  doesn't exist

-------- Analysis Performance Metrics ------------------------------------------                                                                                        --------------------
[--] innodb_stats_on_metadata: OFF
[OK] No stat updates during querying INFORMATION_SCHEMA.
Use of uninitialized value $opt{"structstat"} in numeric eq (==) at
        ./mysqltuner.pl line 5810 (#1)
    (W uninitialized) An undefined value was used as if it were already
    defined.  It was interpreted as a "" or a 0, but maybe it was a mistake.
    To suppress this warning assign a defined value to your variables.

    To help you figure out what was undefined, perl will try to tell you
    the name of the variable (if any) that was undefined.  In some cases
    it cannot do this, so it also tells you what operation you used the
    undefined value in.  Note, however, that perl optimizes your program
    and the operation displayed in the warning may not necessarily appear
    literally in your program.  For example, "that $foo" is usually
    optimized into "that " . $foo, and the warning will refer to the
    concatenation (.) operator, even though there is no . in
    your program.

-------- CVE Security Recommendations ------------------------------------------                                                                                        --------------------
[OK] NO SECURITY CVE FOUND FOR YOUR VERSION

-------- Performance Metrics ---------------------------------------------------                                                                                        --------------------
[--] Up for: 3d 0h 50m 58s (27M q [106.285 qps], 5M conn, TX: 29G, RX: 3G)
[--] Reads / Writes: 92% / 8%
[--] Binary logging is disabled
[--] Physical Memory     : 31.3G
[--] Max MySQL memory    : 86.1G
[--] Other process memory: 0B
[--] Total buffers: 15.3G global + 480.6M per thread (151 max threads)
[--] Performance_schema Max memory usage: 0B
[--] Galera GCache Max memory usage: 0B
[!!] Maximum reached memory usage: 86.6G (276.42% of installed RAM)
[!!] Maximum possible memory usage: 86.1G (274.92% of installed RAM)
[!!] Overall possible memory usage with other process exceeded memory
[OK] Slow queries: 0% (27/27M)
[!!] Highest connection usage: 100% (152/151)
[OK] Aborted connections: 0.21% (12101/5634183)
[!!] Name resolution is active: a reverse name resolution is made for each new c                                                                                        onnection which can reduce performance
[OK] Query cache is disabled by default due to mutex contention on multiprocesso                                                                                        r machines.
[OK] Sorts requiring temporary tables: 0% (0 temp sorts / 1M sorts)
[!!] Joins performed without indexes: 30037
[OK] Temporary tables created on disk: 2% (28K on disk / 997K total)
[OK] Thread cache hit rate: 99% (253 created / 5M connections)
[OK] Table cache hit rate: 99% (26M hits / 27M requests)
[!!] table_definition_cache (400) is less than number of tables (3041)
[OK] Open file limit used: 0% (121/16K)
[OK] Table locks acquired immediately: 100% (189K immediate / 189K locks)

-------- Performance schema ----------------------------------------------------                                                                                        --------------------
[!!] Performance_schema should be activated.
[--] Sys schema is installed.

-------- ThreadPool Metrics ----------------------------------------------------                                                                                        --------------------
[--] ThreadPool stat is disabled.
Use of uninitialized value $opt{"myisamstat"} in numeric eq (==) at
        ./mysqltuner.pl line 3860 (#1)

-------- InnoDB Metrics --------------------------------------------------------                                                                                        --------------------
[--] InnoDB is enabled.
[OK] InnoDB File per table is activated
[OK] InnoDb Buffer Pool size ( 128.0M ) under limit for 64 bits architecture: (1                                                                                        7179869184.0G )
[!!] InnoDB buffer pool / data size: 128.0M / 33.4G
[!!] Ratio InnoDB log file size / InnoDB Buffer pool size (75%): 96.0M * 1 / 128                                                                                        .0M should be equal to 25%
[--] Number of InnoDB Buffer Pool Chunk: 1 for 1 Buffer Pool Instance(s)
[OK] Innodb_buffer_pool_size aligned with Innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size & Innodb                                                                                        _buffer_pool_instances
[OK] InnoDB Read buffer efficiency: 99.87% (157285991602 hits / 157486582048 tot                                                                                        al)
[!!] InnoDB Write Log efficiency: 49.38% (563905 hits / 1141959 total)
[OK] InnoDB log waits: 0.00% (0 waits / 578054 writes)

-------- Aria Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------                                                                                        --------------------
[--] Aria Storage Engine is enabled.
[OK] Aria pagecache size / total Aria indexes: 128.0M/336.0K
[OK] Aria pagecache hit rate: 99.9% (27M cached / 27K reads)

-------- TokuDB Metrics --------------------------------------------------------                                                                                        --------------------
[--] TokuDB is disabled.

-------- XtraDB Metrics --------------------------------------------------------                                                                                        --------------------
[--] XtraDB is disabled.

-------- Galera Metrics --------------------------------------------------------                                                                                        --------------------
[--] Galera is disabled.

-------- Replication Metrics ---------------------------------------------------                                                                                        --------------------
[--] Galera Synchronous replication: NO
[--] No replication slave(s) for this server.
[--] Binlog format: MIXED
[--] XA support enabled: ON
[--] Semi synchronous replication Master: OFF
[--] Semi synchronous replication Slave: OFF
[--] This is a standalone server
```

mysqltuner recommendation

```
-------- Recommendations -------------------------------------------------------                                                                                        --------------------
General recommendations:
    Reduce your overall MySQL memory footprint for system stability
    Dedicate this server to your database for highest performance.
    Reduce or eliminate persistent connections to reduce connection usage
    Configure your accounts with ip or subnets only, then update your configuration with skip-name-resolve=ON
    We will suggest raising the 'join_buffer_size' until JOINs not using indexes are found.
             See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/join-buffer-size.html
             (specially the conclusions at the bottom of the page).
    Performance schema should be activated for better diagnostics
    Be careful, increasing innodb_log_file_size / innodb_log_files_in_group means higher crash recovery mean time
Variables to adjust:
  *** MySQL's maximum memory usage is dangerously high ***
  *** Add RAM before increasing MySQL buffer variables ***
    max_connections (> 151)
    wait_timeout (< 28800)
    interactive_timeout (< 28800)
    skip-name-resolve=ON
    join_buffer_size (> 256.0K, or always use indexes with JOINs)
    table_definition_cache (400) > 3041 or -1 (autosizing if supported)
    performance_schema=ON
    innodb_buffer_pool_size (>= 33.4G) if possible.
    innodb_log_file_size should be (=32M) if possible, so InnoDB total log file                                                                                         size equals 25% of buffer pool size.
```

my cnf
please give suggestion please what need to add

```
[client-server]
# Port or socket location where to connect
# port = 3306
socket = /run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

# Import all .cnf files from configuration directory
!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
!includedir /etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/
```

I would greatly appreciate any insights, explanations, or resources related to using mysqltuner for MariaDB performance tuning. Thank you in advance for your valuable assistance!

Comment: FWIW, if users are complaining certain queries are slow, then it's more likely an issue with those queries / how the database is architected, and not so much a configuration problem. You would have to run those slow queries with their `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` and share it for further help diagnosing the root issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Big issue:  Change `innodb_buffer_pool_size` to `20G`.

Fix that, run for a couple of days, then let's see how things are.

More tools:

- More thorough analysis: https://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis#tuning
- SlowLog: https://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis#slow_queries_and_slowlog

Comment: was `innodb_buffer_pool_size ` set to _InnoDb Buffer Pool size ( 128.0M )_?